# flutter - handling json data

Tags: json, flutter

I need your help with handling the data of my app. I've already researched a lot about my problem but havent found a working answer...

Here's my problem:
I want my app to display human bones. The data which i want to be displayed is stored in a JSON file (it's not the whole json file because it just repeats over and over again. colsing brackets aren't the error):

```
{

"bones": 
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Humerus",
        "image": "assets/images/...",
        "locations": [
            {
            "location1": [
                {
                "id": "11",
                "title": "proximal",
                "image": "assets/images/...",
                "subcategory1": [
                    {
                    "id": "11A",
                    "title": "extraartikulär 2-Segment unifokal",
                    "image": "assets/images/...",
                    "subsubcategory1": [{
                        "id": "11A1",
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11A1.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11A1.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11A1.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory2": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "11A2",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11A2.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11A2.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11A2.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory3": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "11A3",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11A3.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11A3.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11A3.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }]
                }],
                "subcategory2": [{
                    "id": "11B",
                    "title": "extraartikulär 2-Segment unifokal",
                    "image": "assets/images/...",
                    "subsubcategory1": [{
                        "id": "11B1",
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11B1.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11B1.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11B1.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory2": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "11B2",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11B2.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11B2.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11B2.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory3": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "11B3",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11B3.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11B3.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11B3.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }]
                }],
                "subcategory3": [{
                    "id": "11C",
                    "title": "extraartikulär 2-Segment unifokal",
                    "image": "assets/images/...",
                    "subsubcategory1": [{
                        "id": "11C1",
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11C1.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11C1.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11C1.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory2": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "11C2",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11C2.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11C2.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11C2.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory3": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "11C3",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11C3.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "11C3.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "11C3.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }]
                }]

            }],
            "location2": [
                {
                "id": "12",
                "title": "diaphysär",
                "image": "assets/images/...",
                "subcategory1": [{
                    "id": "12A",
                    "title": "extraartikulär 2-Segment unifokal",
                    "image": "assets/images/...",
                    "subsubcategory1": [{
                        "id": "12A1",
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "12A1.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12A1.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12A1.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory2": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "12A2",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11A2.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12A2.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12A2.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory3": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "12A3",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "12A3.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12A3.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12A3.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }]
                }],
                "subcategory2": [{
                    "id": "12B",
                    "title": "extraartikulär 2-Segment unifokal",
                    "image": "assets/images/...",
                    "subsubcategory1": [{
                        "id": "12B1",
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "12B1.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12B1.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12B1.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory2": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "12B2",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "12B2.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12B2.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12B2.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory3": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "12B3",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "12B3.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12B3.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12B3.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }]
                }],
                "subcategory3": [{
                    "id": "12C",
                    "title": "extraartikulär 2-Segment unifokal",
                    "image": "assets/images/...",
                    "subsubcategory1": [{
                        "id": "12C1",
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "12C1.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12C1.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12C1.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory2": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "12C2",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11C2.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12C2.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12C2.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }],
                    "subsubcategory3": [{
                        "title": "Abriß des Tuberculum majus",
                        "id": "12C3",
                        "image": "assets/images/...",
                        "final_item1": {
                            "id": "11C3.1",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item2": {
                            "id": "12C3.2",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        },
                        "final_item3": {
                            "id": "12C3.3",
                            "title": "Tuberculum majus ohne Dislokation",
                            "image": "assets/images/...",
                            "model": "assets/images/..."
                        }
                    }]
                }]

            }]

        }]
    }
]}
```

There are 3 locations each with 3 subcategories with each 3 subsubcategories with each 3 final items.

Currently im just trying to print the name of the bone in the console. I got these classes:

```
class Bone {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<Locations> locations;

  Bone({this.id, this.imageUrl, this.name, this.locations});
  factory Bone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Bone(
    id: json['id'],
    name: json['name'],
    imageUrl: json['image'],
    locations: json['locations']
    );
  }
}

class Locations{
  final List<Location> location;

  Locations(this.location);
}

class Location{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<Subcategory> subcategory;

  Location({this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.subcategory});
}

class Subcategory{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<Subsubcategory> subsubcategory;

  Subcategory({this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.subsubcategory});
}

class Subsubcategory{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final FinalItem finalItem;

  Subsubcategory({this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.finalItem});
}

class FinalItem{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;

  FinalItem({this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl});
}
```

And this test screen:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../models/bone.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/test';

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {


  Future<String> loadDataFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/api/data.json');
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    String jsonString = await loadDataFromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Bone bone = Bone.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('Name ${bone.name}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),

    );
  }
}
```

This error is thrown in my debug console:

E/flutter ( 7644): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Thank you in advance :)

https://pastebin.com/utpKhnYx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Models:**

```
class Bone {
  List<Bones> bones;

  Bone({this.bones});

  Bone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['bones'] != null) {
      bones = new List<Bones>();
      json['bones'].forEach((v) {
        bones.add(new Bones.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.bones != null) {
      data['bones'] = this.bones.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Bones {
  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  List<Locations> locations;

  Bones({this.id, this.name, this.image, this.locations});

  Bones.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    image = json['image'];
    if (json['locations'] != null) {
      locations = new List<Locations>();
      json['locations'].forEach((v) {
        locations.add(new Locations.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    if (this.locations != null) {
      data['locations'] = this.locations.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Locations {
  List<Location> location1;
  List<Location> location2;
  List<Location> location3;

  Locations({this.location1, this.location2, this.location3});

  Locations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['location1'] != null) {
      location1 = new List<Location>();
      json['location1'].forEach((v) {
        location1.add(new Location.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['location2'] != null) {
      location2 = new List<Location>();
      json['location2'].forEach((v) {
        location2.add(new Location.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['location3'] != null) {
      location3 = new List<Location>();
      json['location3'].forEach((v) {
        location3.add(new Location.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.location1 != null) {
      data['location1'] = this.location1.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.location2 != null) {
      data['location2'] = this.location2.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.location3 != null) {
      data['location3'] = this.location3.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Location {
  String id;
  String title;
  String image;
  List<Subcategory> subcategory1;
  List<Subcategory> subcategory2;
  List<Subcategory> subcategory3;

  Location(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.image,
        this.subcategory1,
        this.subcategory2,
        this.subcategory3});

  Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    if (json['subcategory1'] != null) {
      subcategory1 = new List<Subcategory>();
      json['subcategory1'].forEach((v) {
        subcategory1.add(new Subcategory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['subcategory2'] != null) {
      subcategory2 = new List<Subcategory>();
      json['subcategory2'].forEach((v) {
        subcategory2.add(new Subcategory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['subcategory3'] != null) {
      subcategory3 = new List<Subcategory>();
      json['subcategory3'].forEach((v) {
        subcategory3.add(new Subcategory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    if (this.subcategory1 != null) {
      data['subcategory1'] = this.subcategory1.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.subcategory2 != null) {
      data['subcategory2'] = this.subcategory2.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.subcategory3 != null) {
      data['subcategory3'] = this.subcategory3.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Subcategory {
  String id;
  String title;
  String image;
  List<Subsubcategory> subsubcategory1;
  List<Subsubcategory> subsubcategory2;
  List<Subsubcategory> subsubcategory3;

  Subcategory(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.image,
        this.subsubcategory1,
        this.subsubcategory2,
        this.subsubcategory3});

  Subcategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    if (json['subsubcategory1'] != null) {
      subsubcategory1 = new List<Subsubcategory>();
      json['subsubcategory1'].forEach((v) {
        subsubcategory1.add(new Subsubcategory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['subsubcategory2'] != null) {
      subsubcategory2 = new List<Subsubcategory>();
      json['subsubcategory2'].forEach((v) {
        subsubcategory2.add(new Subsubcategory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['subsubcategory3'] != null) {
      subsubcategory3 = new List<Subsubcategory>();
      json['subsubcategory3'].forEach((v) {
        subsubcategory3.add(new Subsubcategory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    if (this.subsubcategory1 != null) {
      data['subsubcategory1'] =
          this.subsubcategory1.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.subsubcategory2 != null) {
      data['subsubcategory2'] =
          this.subsubcategory2.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.subsubcategory3 != null) {
      data['subsubcategory3'] =
          this.subsubcategory3.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Subsubcategory {
  String id;
  String title;
  String image;
  FinalItem1 finalItem1;
  FinalItem1 finalItem2;
  FinalItem1 finalItem3;

  Subsubcategory(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.image,
        this.finalItem1,
        this.finalItem2,
        this.finalItem3});

  Subsubcategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    finalItem1 = json['final_item1'] != null
        ? new FinalItem1.fromJson(json['final_item1'])
        : null;
    finalItem2 = json['final_item2'] != null
        ? new FinalItem1.fromJson(json['final_item2'])
        : null;
    finalItem3 = json['final_item3'] != null
        ? new FinalItem1.fromJson(json['final_item3'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    if (this.finalItem1 != null) {
      data['final_item1'] = this.finalItem1.toJson();
    }
    if (this.finalItem2 != null) {
      data['final_item2'] = this.finalItem2.toJson();
    }
    if (this.finalItem3 != null) {
      data['final_item3'] = this.finalItem3.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class FinalItem1 {
  String id;
  String title;
  String image;
  String model;

  FinalItem1({this.id, this.title, this.image, this.model});

  FinalItem1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    model = json['model'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**TestScreen:**

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/test';

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {


  Future<String> loadDataFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/api/data.json');
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    String jsonString = await loadDataFromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Bone bone = Bone.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('Name ${bone.bones[0].name}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this isnt working. 'I/flutter ( 7644): Name: null'

Comment: i also got a compiler message: lib/models/bone.dart:13:66: Error: Method not found: 'Locations.fromJson'.
    locations: (json['locations'] as List)?.map((i) => Locations.fromJson(i))?.toList()

Comment: Your models are incorrect.Please add fromJson methods for all your models.It will fix it.

Comment: You can share one json object and I'll generate models for you to understand.

Comment: i added from json methods to every class but it still returns null -.- that would be nice but i didnt understand what you excactely mean

Comment: Please share your json file.

Comment: how can i do this properly? i'm new to stack overflow... i updated the code without the thrid location

Comment: Please use PasteBin and share link in your question by updating it.

Comment: I've updated my answer.Please try this.You were incorrectly parsing lists in your Models.This works now.I've printed name of the bone of first index in bones list.

Comment: Moreover the data in your json file is very complex and unnecessarily structured. Please learn more about storing lists in json.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah it is the first time for me using json